# Remove pagination in organic groups people list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, organic-groups

I must remove pagination in admin people page `group/node/[nid]/admin/people`. Is it posible?

I'm using devel module to view form structure and `hook_alter_form`.

I appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure this in the Views UI.

1. Make sure the **Views UI** module is enabled at `/admin/modules#views`
2. Go to `/admin/structure/views/view/og_members_admin/edit/default`
3. Under *Pager > User pager*, click the *Full* link.
4. Make sure the radio button for *"Display all items"* is checked.
5. Click **Apply** and **save** the view.

That should do it.

Comment: I haven't this view in og 7.x-1.5, in 7.x-2rc it is here, thank you very much :)